# Unable to get the proper XPath for webpage elements in import.io's crawler

Tags: xml, xpath, web-crawler, import.io

I am trying to create a .csv file with the movies data from the website Allociné (the largest French movie database) for a research project, using import.io's Crawler because my programming knowledge is poor (currently doing a PhD in Ecology) and having an easy-to-understand tool seemed like the best idea.

For every movie I need:

1. the Title of the movie
2. the Release date ('Date de Sortie' in FR)
3. the Genre(s) of the movie

Here is an example of an Allociné movie page (for Star Wars I): http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=20754.html

At first I tried using import.io's selection tool, but it did not work because some movies have two release dates instead of one (like SW1 above - original release in 1999 and 3D release ('reprise') in 2012) - which screwed with the Crawler. So I had to use XPaths to identify the elements I need. The Title works just fine (using `//title`) but I have issues with release dates and genres.

For release dates, the XPath I extracted from the source of the page is:

```
//*[@id="col_main"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/strong/span
```

I added `/@content` at the end to get the date in yyyy-MM-dd format, which led to:

```
//*[@id="col_main"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/strong/span/@content
```

However, import.io does not recognize the element I need him to find.

For Genres, same thing, I got this XPath from Chrome for the first Genre (Science-fiction):

```
//*[@id="col_main"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/a[1]/span
```

I need import.io to gather all Genres, so I removed the `[1]` from `a[1]` to get the entirety of `a`.

```
//*[@id="col_main"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/a/span
```

It does not work either, import.io returns a null element.

So, any explanation on why it is not working would be extremely appreciated! And sorry if I missed something glaringly obvious, as I said, I am not a specialist at all.

Blaise

Answer (score 2):

For the release date try:

//span[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content

This basically means: find a span node that has an attribute called "datePublished" and extract the attribute called "content"

And for the genre try:

//span[@itemprop="genre"]/text()

This one means find a span node that has an attribute named "genre" and extract the text that follows it.